# Blender Donut, icing got displaced, won't save position when I close out bender and open back up

Tags: objects, saving

I am almost done with the donut tutorial from blender guru, and came across a problem where every time I close and open up blender the icing seems to be misplaced on the donut by about an inch or so off to the side.

I move the icing again and line it up so it is correctly placed on the donut again, save, and when I open blender back up it does the same thing and misplaces the icing. Seems like I am moving the object and it is not saving the movement.

Comment: Press N in the 3D viewport with your object selected and see if you've accidentally keyframed any of the location parameters (you'll know because the color will be different). Also check the Object Properties Tab (Orange "Box-ish" looking thing) and see if any _Delta Transforms_ have been set.